# Automaticaly hard reset website

Tags: javascript

I want to make a hard reset page so that every user who returns to the page had the current look of the page.
I tried `location.reload (true)` but this is starting to unveil me for infinity.

Comment: Could you add more clarification of your goal?

Comment: If you mean that users get old versions of the website after you've updated it, you could try using shorter cache times.

Comment: Shilly, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The funnest part of development is learning what you don't know, so you can learn it. The problem you're facing is caching. It's a pretty popular topic in web development, as you can't simply tell everyone using your site to hard refresh the page when it's out of date. What you can do however is "bust the cache".

One of the more common cache busting techniques is to add a query to the get request, for example. If you have a Javascript file to include in your page, `main.js` you can make your script tag look like this `<script src="main.js?version=1"></script>`. This will tell a visitors browser to load version 1 of your main.js file. When you change main.js increment the number to 2. When the browser hits your server, your server will say, Oh no main.js version 1 is gone, but 2 is available. The server then loads the newest version of main.js. At the same time the user will benefit from caching only the **current version** of your page. There are a lot of different server side bundlers that will also handle this problem for you.

A lot of people will do this technique by adding a date to the script populated by their server environment, or something else that will auto increment. How your stack is setup will add enough variance to this answer that you'd want to search elsewhere. For example, if you use C# for your backend, search `C# cachebusting` and you'll see a lot of solutions to your problem.

Comment: Can you do that with css by adding versions?

Comment: Yes you can cache bust CSS files in the same way.