# Server caching php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following simple php script on my server

```
$data=file_get_contents('data.txt');

$ar = explode("\n",$data);

$json = array();


foreach($ar as $a)
{

    $br = explode("|",$a);
    $json[]=array("lat"=>str_replace("\r", '', $br[0]),"lang"=>str_replace("\r", '', $br[1]));


}

echo json_encode($json);
```

?>

I also have a small page with javascript that gets the output of the php file. problem is that the javascript page when loaded in my browser shows the same output no matter how I change the data.txt file. But if I pull up the php file in my browser the javascript file shows the changes to data.txt. Is the server caching php files?

Comment: more likely your browser

Comment: [Does this answer help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48949538/7314155)

Comment: Ok it is definitely in the browser but how can I make the following code grab the file fresh everytime and not cache it?                                                               

    function load_map()
 {
  
   
   $.ajax({
   url: "locations.php", 
   success: function(result){
  
  show_map(result);
    
   
    
    }
 
 });

Comment: @user1724365 Look at the `cache` parameter in the docs. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Ok, it was my ajax call in my script. Added $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); and it fixed it.